# Ruby: 'require' returns false even though file not loaded

Tags: ruby, require

I have this code:

```
puts require './item'
puts $"

class Light < Item
  #code
end
```

`Item` class in `item.rb`:

```
require './v3d'
require './ray'

class Item
  attr_accessor :pos 

  def initialize(pos)
    @pos = pos
  end

  def check(pos, dir)
    return nil
  end

  def normal(ray)
    return nil
  end
end
```

that when I run my program prints this output:

```
false
enumerator.so
thread.rb
rational.so
complex.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.3.0/enc/encdb.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.3.0/enc/trans/transdb.so
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/unicode_normalize.rb
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.3.0/rbconfig.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/errors.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/version.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/platform.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/util/list.rb
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.3.0/stringio.so
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/version.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/core_ext/name_error.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/levenshtein.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/spell_checkable.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/delegate.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/class_name_checker.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/variable_name_checker.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/method_name_checker.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/null_checker.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/formatter.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean.rb
/home/<user>/Documents/ruby/ray/write_ppm.rb
/home/<user>/Documents/ruby/ray/v3d.rb
/home/<user>/Documents/ruby/ray/pixel.rb
/home/<user>/Documents/ruby/ray/image.rb
/home/<user>/Documents/ruby/ray/material.rb
```

then throws:

```
/home/<user>/Documents/ruby/ray/light.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Item (NameError)
```

When `require './item'` is called, there is no error AND it returns false. From my understanding of how `require` works, it seems that the program incorrectly thinks it does not need to load `item.rb`. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Edit: expanded on some code

Comment: Can you show us how your item.rb looks like? Feel like there might be something wrong with the definition of your class.

Comment: `item.rb` just contains the creation of the `Item` class. Its only purpose is to have child classes so there's almost no code. What I think is relevant is that `require './item'` returns false with no errors, but it's clear from `puts $"` that `item.rb` has never been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by totally rewriting my `require` statements for every file. What I think the problem was, was this:

- `item.rb` contained `require './ray'`
- `ray.rb` contained `require './light'`
- `light.rb` contained `require './item'` and `class Light < Item`

While loading `item.rb`, the interpreter saw it needed to also load `ray.rb` and therefore `light.rb`. When it reached the `require './item'` inside `light.rb`, it returned false because it was in the process of loading that file. However, since it was not yet finished loading, it did not show up in `$"`. The interpreter then needed access to the definition of the `Item` class to finish loading `light.rb`, but because it needed to finish loading `light.rb` to load `item.rb`, the interpreter thew a `NameError`.

Answer (score 2):

As a generic answer, not related to op, but because I had a similar issue and was pointed here by search engines.

Basically `require 'http'` returned false while gem was not loaded.

I figured out that there is a `http.rb` file inside load path and it is being loaded instead of the standard gem. So double check there are no conflicting file names of ruby files under library load path and the gem name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want `require_relative` instead.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative

vs

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require

Comment: I have tried using `require_relative`, and it has the same effect. What I'm most confused about is what `require './item'` and `require_relative 'item'` both return `false` with no errors, yet from `puts $"`, it is clear that `item.rb` has not been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that if `require 'my_lib'` returns false, then `'my_lib'` has already been loaded. However this is different from saying that a `MyLib` class is defined. Does your item.rb define an `Item` class?

Also, it may be possible that Item is defined somewhere else in the namespace hierarchy. e.g. if your item.rb is in some_gem/item.rb, and you're calling require from some_gem/, it will load successfully, but the name of the class might be `SomeGem::Item`. In this case you wouldn't be able to access it directly from the root namespace.

Last thing I can think of is that the item.rb file is changing under, or otherwise has some very dynamic pieces that are confusing the interpreter.

I would think that the issue is one of these before thinking that require is somehow messing up.

Comment: Yes, the `Item` class is defined in the `item.rb` file, and there very little code in it. The result of the `puts $"` call shows that `item.rb` was not loaded, even though the (earlier) `require './item'` call returned false without errors.

Comment: Very strange... It's definitely able to find the file, or else it would raise a LoadError. `require` and `$"` both normally have very consistent behavior, so I'm guessing that either a) we're overlooking something dumb somewhere or b) there's some crazy meta-programming going on. Could you give us some more information? Say, the content of item.rb and the full output of puts `$"`? Without more information we really can't do more than speculate.

Comment: I added `item.rb` and all output from `$"`